# How to get functionality from js file to htm file

Tags: jquery, html

I have a htm file containing this code:

```
<div id="this-item">
    <a onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-overview"> </i>
        <span class="nav-item"> Overview </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and a js file:

```
function myFunction()
{
    $("#this-item").show();
}

window.initDashboard = function () {

};
```

What I've tried here is to get into htm the functionality of myFunction(). When the text is clicked, it should show something but as it is now I get an error saying this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

What did I do wrong, how can I solve this?

Comment: Try removing the dot from `function.myFunction`

Comment: Replace the dot between function and myFunction by a space. Voting to close as off-topic because this is a simple typographical error.

Comment: done that, still same error

Comment: Where is your script tag located? It should be after the function call and preferably at the bottom of your document just before closing the body tag.

Comment: Load `.js` file or the `javascript` before the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
alert('some text');
  $("#this-item").html('some text');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="this-item">
  <a onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-overview"> </i>
    <span class="nav-item"> Overview </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

show() is of no use which is already showing. So, instead have replaced the html content with 'some text' to just showcase myfunction() is working.

Answer (score 1):

delete dot in your code

```
function myFunction()
{
    $("#this-item").show();
}

window.initDashboard = function () {

};
```

Comment: have you link your js file to your html file?

Comment: yes, still didn't work. I made it work by doing this `<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      ...
    }
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you import the js file with myFunction() in your HTML? See this doc for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: yes, I did it like that but didn't work so I moved the js function into the htm file like this: `<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        ...
    }
</script>`

Comment: Ok, good that was solved, but check the js file name and path if they are correct to put the js code outside of HTMLis a best pratice